# How do I break out of an iFrame only for certain domains?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
if (top.location!= self.location) {
        top.location = self.location.href
    }
```

If someone has my site in an iFrame, this will break out.

However, I only want to do it for certain domains. How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another condition...

```
var allowedDomains = ["stackoverflow.com"];

if (allowedDomains.indexOf(top.location.hostname) == -1 
    && top.location!= self.location) {
    top.location = self.location.href
}
```

Comment: Can you get the location of a window from a different server? I thought you couldn't

Comment: @JuanMendes If you couldn't, then the OP's original code wouldn't work I believe.